# On Button click, dropdown loses its value

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdowns. First is for State and second is one for the City. When I select the state, its respective city gets populated in the next dropdown. I have one option to add more cities through textbox on button click while selecting the Other option from the city dropdownlist.

The issue is that whenever i am adding the city from the textbox, the it gets inserted into the respective state and also the dropdownlist loses its value. I tried debugging but couldn't find the exact issue.

Please see the code for your reference:

```
protected void btnAddDropDown_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "Add_CityforLocation";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 0;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CountryName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "India";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CityName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtOtherCity.Text.Trim();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StateName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddllocation1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            BindContrydropdown();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);//You Can Haave Messagebox here
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}

protected void BindContrydropdown()
{
    //conenction path for database
    //string connection = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Id,CityName From Career.Location", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        ddllocation1.DataSource = ds;
        ddllocation1.DataTextField = "CityName";
        ddllocation1.DataValueField = "Id";
        ddllocation1.DataBind();
        ddllocation1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
        ddllocation1.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("--OTHER--", "0"));
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Also, see the HTML for the same:-

```
 <tr>
        <td class="td">Location/State</td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList CssClass="txtfld-popup" ID="ddllocation1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddllocation1_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="error_msg" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="ddllocation1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter location" InitialValue="--Select--" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="td">Location/City</td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList CssClass="txtfld-popup" ID="ddlLocation" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLocation_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="error_msg" ID="reqLocation" ControlToValidate="ddlLocation" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter location" InitialValue="--Select--" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtOtherCity" runat="server" Visible="false" CssClass="txtfld-popup"></asp:TextBox>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAddDropDown" runat="server" Width="63" Text="Add" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnAddDropDown_Click1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: You need to remember that postback clears values..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
try
{

    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        BindContrydropdown();
    }

}
```

Comment: Now values are not been getting inserted in the city table. why ?

Comment: anything else. Please see my js fiddle for your reference http://jsfiddle.net/Lm7o1y9x/. whenever I add the BindContrydropdown() to pageload it gives me 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'StateName'. Also, the value is not inserted in the CityDropdown

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.

Comment: What's happening is that postback refreshes values, Try to put this in an updatepanel, that way it will not cause complete postback